# Modify the url of the web application with jboss 4.2.3

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, jboss

i'm need to changed or hide the url of my web application deploy in jboss to the user because it's to long here's an example

my current url is:

`www.example.com:8180/blazedsExample/Example/Example.html`

i just want that the url was

`www.example.com`

thansk for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use many free url shorten services.Goole is also offering such kind of service.
Use http://goo.gl/ and enter your URL there , that will give you a shortened url.
To use this service in your application,call /action/shorten action and pass input text field (id) replaced with your value(www.example.com:8180/blazedsExample/Example/Example.html).That will return shortened URL.You can make above call using  java.net.URLConnection class.
Hope this will help.